# Making a triangle with CSS3 that includes a inner arrow?

Tags: html, css

I would like to make an arrow like so:

[image: arrow]

Is this possible with just CSS3, Notice how it's a black arrow with an inner white arrow slightly -1px from the black. Ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite so sure it is possible (at least outside FF).  the traditional way would be with a border hack but that requires a flat color.  It seems you are using a gradient as the fill for the triangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with just a singular `div` and CSS3 transformations. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yVTr3/5/

It could easily be modified to adapt to the size and exact colors you would need.

Comment: Updated to include more browsers - http://jsfiddle.net/yVTr3/7/

Great job man - that's excellent.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that, even with css 2.1 - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/
However you'll need to create 3 arrows one on top of each other - black + white + black - and position them accordingly (1px from right for the middle one, 2px from right for the topmost)